# Content of fieldset is moving out of legend container

Tags: html, css

I was looking at many pages to find out what I am doing wrong, but can't find anything helpful. So the problem is that my text inside fieldset tag is going out of it's borders.

This is how I want it to look:

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Gux.png)

[How it looks actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmsfa.png)

```css
body {
  height: 660px;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="Mister" name="Title" value="mister">
    <label for="Mister">Mister</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="Miss" name="Title" value="miss">
    <label for="Miss">Miss</label>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is?

```css
body {
  height: 660px;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  position:relative;
}

fieldset p {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:0px;
}

fieldset p:nth-child(2) {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
}

fieldset p input {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:0px;
}

fieldset p label {
  position:absolute;
  left:35px;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="Mister" name="Title" value="mister">
    <label for="Mister">Mister</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="Miss" name="Title" value="miss">
    <label for="Miss">Miss</label>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It worked great, thanks for helping, now I know what should I look at next time!

Comment: @Jessus it's a bad idea to use `position` for such a trivial issue. You can get the same results with much less code, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraphs usually have default margins. Zero them out:

```css
body {
  height: 660px;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
}

fieldset p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="Mister" name="Title" value="mister">
    <label for="Mister">Mister</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="Miss" name="Title" value="miss">
    <label for="Miss">Miss</label>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It only helped a bit, but didn't solve the problem, but thanks for helping.

Comment: @Jessus Please explain how it did not solve the problem. It looks exactly like the picture you posted said it should look.

Comment: @Jessus You're saying that when you click the run code snippet in my answer that's what you're seeing, or when you use the CSS I gave you in your project that's what you're seeing?

Comment: I linked what I see in my project, after I used CSS you gave me.

Comment: @Jessus Then you code you provided in your question is not a [mcve]. We need to be able to reproduce what you're experiencing.

Comment: So should I post my whole code, because honestly I have no idea what is wrong?

Comment: @Jessus No, you should not post your whole code. You should post a **minimal** example as the link in my previous comment states. If you think that would be difficult, then you should spend some time narrowing the problem down by reducing your code to a bare minimum example.

Answer (score 0):

try both fields in one para. Like below

```
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Title</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="Mister" name="Title" value="mister">
            <label for="Mister">Mister</label>
            <input type="radio" id="Miss" name="Title" value="miss">
            <label for="Miss">Miss</label>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Nothing changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

## <del>`<p>`aragraphs</del>

**`<p>` tags should contain text, not `<input>` tags.**

- Remove all `<p>` tags.
- Wrap each `<label>` tag around the corresponding `<input>` tag.
- Next, add the following ruleset to stylesheet or `<style>` tag:

  > ```
  >  label {
  >    display: block;
  >  }
  > ```

---

### Demo

```css
body {
  height: 660px;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>

  <label for="Mister">
    <input type="radio" id="Mister" name="Title" value="mister"> Mister
  </label>

  <label for="Miss">
    <input type="radio" id="Miss" name="Title" value="miss"> Miss
  </label>

</fieldset>
```